# How to set a Template Binding URL Prefix in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a UI with hundreds of knockout templates. It is time to develop another UI. I need to prefix the old references to template file urls with "uiv1". Forexample, wherever I say

```
data-bind="name: 'admin/dashboard'"
```

I would expect it to resolve to

```
data-base="name: 'uiv1/admin/dashboard'
```

Is there any easy way to configure that in knockout? For example, some config I can pass to ko.applyBindings()? I did not see anything in the source there but perhaps theres some other way I am missing.

Comment: for my information, how template name are resolved to file url? It's not standard KO stuff, is it?

Comment: I think it comes from taking the base url ("http(s)" plus "www.domainName.com" plus a "/") followed by the relative URL you specify in knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be better to rename all instances if possible.

otherwise, here is a hackish way to do it.

```js
var old_template = ko.bindingHandlers['template'];
var prefix = 'uiv1/'

// modifying template binding
ko.bindingHandlers['template'] = {
  'init': function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var bindingValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (typeof bindingValue === 'string') bindingValue = prefix + bindingValue;
    else if (bindingValue.name) bindingValue.name = prefix + bindingValue.name;
    return old_template.init(element, function() {
      return bindingValue
    });
  },
  'update': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    return old_template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
  }
}

// view model
var vm = {
  buyer: { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 },
  seller: { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 },
  original: { name: 'original', credits: 20000 }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('modified'));

//resetting it to original
ko.bindingHandlers['template'] = old_template;

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('original'));
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="uiv1/admin/dashboard">
  <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3><span>(from: "uiv1/admin/dashboard")</span>
  <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span>
  </p>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="dashboard">
  <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3><span>(from: "dashboard")</span>
  <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span>
  </p>
</script>

<div id="modified">
  Modified Template
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'admin/dashboard', data: buyer }"></div>
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'admin/dashboard', data: seller }"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="original">
  Original Template
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'dashboard', data: original }"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's a good temporary solution for refactoring gradually. Thanks.